# Which queue(Apache kafka, RabbitMQ) is best for sending email on new executer thread which will not affect on api performance in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, jakarta-mail

I am working on Spring Boot. The scenario is the sending of emails which was achieved using java mail sender, but the problem is that rest api have to send email if all operation performed successfully & return success response at end. But if there is Exception occure at a time of sending mail then api is failed. To avoid that case i want to send email on new executer thread so it will not effect on api response. But it is nessecerry to send email. How can i handle this situation. Can i use any queue for sending email ? but I don't know it is possible with queue or not, It it is possible then which is the best queue for sending mail or is there any other solution to handle this situation?
any suggestions how to achieve this ?

I want to try with rabbitMQ but i don't know it will solve the problem or not.

Comment: You can achieve it by using any message broker including rabbitMQ. If you use DB, you can also store the mail in the database and have the scheduler job running and checking if something new there to be send.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have described it seems you are using Synchronous way of communication meaning API has to perform all of the operations along with sending email and at the end, sending the response if everything goes fine. I would recommend to go with Asynchronous communication approach in case of sending email. To do that you can either store your email data in any database or in any messaging broker service like Kafka, RabbitMQ etc.

Suppose you have Service-A which has API exposed which is doing some business operations and once they will get completed then you can store your mail to any of the storage system described above.

Now Create separate microservice(let's named it as `mailing-service`) which will read/fetch the emails from your mail datasource(DB or messaging system like kafka) and will send the email.
If you go with...

**DB storage -** If you use NoSQL DB like MongoDB then you can use it's one of the feature i.e `Change Streams`. MongoDB Change Streams allow applications to access real-time data changes; to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them. Read here- https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/java/java-change-streams/. It comes with sync and async both versions along with Soring boot integration as well.

**Messaging system based storage -** If you go with Kafka, an event streaming platform, you can use `spring-kafka` and @KafkaListener method will automatically receive event(mail in your case). Keep in mind that in kafka, default retention time is seven days but it is configurable. There is no as such restriction in DB based storage system. Kafka topic may have multiple partitions to allow parallel consumption of the messages.